# Transitioning Mannequin models for use in SketchUp - OBJ or FBX and Sub Surf Modifiers?

Tags: mesh, export, obj

I'm looking to purchase some Mannequin models to use in SketchUp because it's my primary modeling software.  I mostly do architectural rendering so at the moment my knowledge of Blender is Part 4 or 5 of the Donut tutorial.

The Mannequins I'm looking to purchase are from Turbosquid and are super high quality - which is great but they're too high quality for SketchUp's limitations.  So I'm thinking about importing the OBJ/FBX formats into Blender (not sure if it can read a 3DS Max format) and try simplifying the surfaces for exporting out to another OBJ or FBX that's more SketchUp friendly.

I guess my question is whether or not this is possible or effective?  Am I thinking about it all wrong?  Basically it's just reducing the polygons and exporting it back out..  At my old job a coworker did a similar process in C4D so I'm hoping Blender has a similar tool.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

T.

Comment: What limitations do you want to overcome in Sketchup ? You may have the same problem loading the file in Blender, if it comes from your computer / graphics card

Comment: It's more the Polygon count.  I'm sure I can open it in Blender just fine; I'm running a Blade Pro with a 3080 in it and 32 GB of RAM.  It's just the complexity of the surface imported directly into SketchUp crashes or won't generate faces between edges if the tolerance between them is too small.  So I'm hoping to just decrease the polygon count in Blender if possible and export it back out.